# Magento Local.xml crashed complete website

Tags: xml, magento

I was hoping anyone could help me with a question. I did try searching stackoverflow for information about local.xml but to no succes.

I wanted to add something to our webstore, and according to a page here on stackoverflow I had to add a certain code. However right after every page went offline. I can't seem to get my magento webstore back online. Now ofcourse I should get our developer company to get it back online, but it's 1:13 AM here and I was kinda hoping anyone here could give a quick to-do.

The file is in app/etc/local.xml. I removed the code that the guy said I should add, but it didn't work anyway. It just gives a 'there has been an error processing your request' page.

Thanks for you time..

The code I was supposed to add is here below.

---

```
...

<stores>
    <admin>
        <dev>
            <debug>
                <template_hints>1</template_hints>
                <template_hints_blocks>1</template_hints_blocks>
            </debug>
        </dev>
    </admin>
</stores>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is enabling template path hints in Magento which allows you to see what blocks are rendered and what template files are being used on the page.

You should enable it this way:

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-template-path-hints-magento

But, **if you only want to see these hints for yourself**, you need to put your IP in the Developer Client Restrictions section.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, but that wasn't the actual problem.. The actual problem is that the complete website is offline after I did that..

Comment: Rofl, I don't know how (I suspect cache) but it just restored itself. Thankyou very much Francis for the hint, I will try that tommorow :-)

Comment: For future reference. The problem with the local.xml isn't solved by Francis his answer in particular (it's just the right way to approach what I was wanting to do in the first place) but in case anyone comes along having the same problem: Just put a placeholder on the website and try again in 30 minutes. Don't freak out like I did :-)

Comment: @Marciplan I wasn't sure if the local.xml will work with enabling template path hints - so I assumed perhaps Magento did not like the XML nodes you inserted in there. Glad to hear you solved the issue though.